# Validation error on AWS EMR with managed scaling policy

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to use the new Managed Scaling Policy in AWS EMR through boto3 client with python. My process reads the configurations from json file and, when running the cluster I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ManagedScalingPolicy", must be one of: Name, LogUri, AdditionalInfo, AmiVersion, ReleaseLabel, Instances, Steps, BootstrapActions, SupportedProducts, NewSupportedProducts, Applications, Configurations, VisibleToAllUsers, JobFlowRole, ServiceRole, Tags, SecurityConfiguration, AutoScalingRole, ScaleDownBehavior, CustomAmiId, EbsRootVolumeSize, RepoUpgradeOnBoot, KerberosAttributes, StepConcurrencyLevel
```

The managed scaling policy is in the root of json file. The documentation of boto3 says that this is the correct place.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Question solved, It was a issue with boto3 version. Updating boto3 with pip solved the problem.

Comment: Can you share the JSON representation of the policy here?